# Xamarin.Forms указание BindingContext через XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, binding

Есть одна ContentPage и две ViewModel. Для всей страницы целиком указан **BindingContext** к **ViewModel1**, но часть элементов внутри некоторой StackLayout нужно забиндить к **ViewModel2**. Я пытаюсь прописать `<StackLayout BindingContext="...` и вот тут у меня возникает затык. Всё, что я бы ни старался там нафантазировать - всё приводит к выбросу исключения `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Reference, x:Reference, Type, x:Type, Static, x:Static и т.п.

1. Что всё это значит в принципе, что когда прописывается и где об этом можно подробно прочитать?
2. Как мне правильно прописать BindingContext исходя из условия задачи?

P.S. ContentPage находится НЕ в том же пространстве имён, что ViewModels

P.S.S. ViewModel1 и ViewModel2 по отношению друг к другу лежат в одном пространстве имён.

P.S.S.S. Заголовочная часть страницы выглядит так:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MobApp.ViewModels"
         xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:MobApp.Themes"
         xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
         x:Class="MobApp.Page"
         BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
         Title="Просто страница">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучите:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm
Путь к классам viewmodel1 и  **viewmodel2** вы уже определили

```
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MobApp.ViewModels"
```

А привязка к любому элементу добавляется следующим образом:

```
        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <ViewModels:**viewmodel2** />
        </StackLayout.BindingContext>
```

При создании экземпляра страницы будет создаваться экземпляр класса **viewmodel2**